# JSMessageViewController = Passing PFObject into (id<JSMessageData>)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, chat

I am using parse as my database to store the text a user enters, and then display it onto the `JSMessageViewController`.

I am having difficulty understanding why my `PFObject` will not pass, and instead, I see empty message cells..

In my code here as you can see, if i pass either of the // code, it crashes, i know `nil` wont work and thats why i am getting the blank... but how do I pass a `PFObject` into the `JSMessageData` ?

```
- (id<JSMessageData>)messageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //PFObject *chat = self.chats[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    //return chat;

    //PFObject *chat = self.chats[indexPath.row];
    //NSString *message = chat[kMMKChatTextKey];
    //return message;

    return nil;

}
```

*JSMessageData has 3 instances :* `- (NSDate *)date`, `- (NSString *)sender`, and `- (NSString *)text` ....

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSMessagesViewController/4.0.0/Protocols/JSMessageData.html

Has anyone worked with this ? or can you help me figure out how I can pass the `PFOject` through - Parse is working fine, and the text entered, and after that when i press send, its stored in Parse.

```
-(void)didSendText:(NSString *)text fromSender:(NSString *)sender onDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    if (text.length != 0){
        PFObject *chat = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Chat"];
        [chat setObject:self.chatRoom    forKey:kMMKChatChatroomKey];
        [chat setObject:self.currentUser forKey:kMMKChatFromUserKey];
        [chat setObject:self.withUser    forKey:kMMKChatToUserKey];
        [chat setObject:text             forKey:kMMKChatTextKey];
        [chat saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            [self.chats addObject:chat];
            //[JSMessageSoundEffect playMessageSentSound];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self finishSend];
            [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
        }];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use objectForKey method on PFObject, and pass appropriate key to retrieve text

Comment: thanks - could you help elaborate one line of the syntax please ?

Comment: I think @turbo means [chats objectForKey:kMMKChatTextKey].  But you could make it much easier for SO to help if you identify exactly which line crashes and paste the console output after the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do what you need.

```
- (id<JSMessageData>)messageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PFObject *chat = self.chats[indexPath.row];
    NSString *message = chat[kMMKChatTextKey];
    JSMessage *jsMessage = [[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:message sender:nil date:nil];
    return jsMessage;
}
```